# Filter rows of one table with conditions coming from another table

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I have a table that stores conditions

```sql
CREATE TABLE conditions (field_id TEXT, value BOOLEAN)
```

With entries like

| field_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| f1 | true |
| f2 | false |

And another table that stores users with field values in a jsonb column

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id BIGINT, fields JSON)
```

With entries like

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"f1":true, "f2":false} |
| 2 | {"f1":true, "f2":true} |
| 3 | {"f1":false, "f2":false} |

I'd like to write a query that returns only the user with 1 in my  example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd suggest to use `jsonb` type instead of `json` (which is essentially a string). And then you can do something like this:

```
select *
from users as u
where
    fields @> (select jsonb_object_agg(c.field_id, c.value) from conditions as c);
```

But you can also expand json and match it like this:

```
select *
from users as u
where
    exists (
        select
        from conditions as c
            left join jsonb_each(u.fields) as f on
                f.key = c.field_id and
                f.value::boolean = c.value
        having
            count(*) = count(f.value)
    );
```

**[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=AuVNPjbU6I)**

Comment: In your second query it also works if there is no condition but I'm not sure to understand how.

Comment: yeah, if there's no condition then subquery returns one row with count(*) = 0. Basically it treats empty conditions table as 'no conditions to apply' and returns everything

Answer (score 3):

**This is a classic [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question,** you just need to unpivot the JSON into separate key/value rows

```sql
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM conditions c
    LEFT JOIN json_each_text(u.fields) j ON c.field_id = j."key" and c.value = j.value::BOOL
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(j.value)  -- every condition is matched
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=64a02e36c5f37fa49465e85a32498413)